# How do I get a range of vertices/edges using a half-edge data structure?

Tags: c#, mesh, vertex, topology

I have a half-edge data structure in 2D which loops through edges in a triangle in a clockwise order. I'm trying to get a range of vertices within a target vertex. Let's say I want all vertices within a depth of 2 like the picture below where the yellow vertex 0 is the target and the green vertices are the one's being retrieved.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbT2h.png

So far this is what I have:

```
public List<Vertex> GetSurroundingVerts(int index)
    {
        List<Vertex> vertContainer = new List<Vertex>();
        HalfEdge startHE = Vertices[index].SourceHE;
        HalfEdge currentHE = startHE;

        vertContainer.Add(startHE.SourceVert);

        do
        {
            vertContainer.Add(currentHE.Next.SourceVert);
            currentHE = currentHE.Twin.Next;
        } while (currentHE != startHE);
        return vertContainer;
    }
```

This works for getting the immediate surrounding vertices of a target vertex but once you increase the range, using this approach for each vertex will be more expensive the larger the range is. For the example picture above we have to check 19 vertices. 19 * 6 = 114 iterations which already becomes more expensive than just using a for-loop and comparing each vertex with the target vertex.

Currently, I'm trying to see if an algorithm that can traverse through the edges in a straight direction is possible (0 to 1 to 7 to 19 to 37 in the picture below) but no luck so far.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNczj.png

What's the best way to go about retrieving the vertices in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this using a simple flooding algorithm. You can still use the code above to find the immediate neighbors, but then you'd mark each as "visited" and use its neighbors as new starting points, until the condition is satisfied.